# Microsoft C++ Pre-defined Macros

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-2010

Is there a cl.exe option to dump all the pre-defined Macros ( along with the defined values ). 
Something like gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null for gcc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think MSVC has a built in way of doing this.

I've used the following program to dump values of 'known' predefined symbols.  I should give attribution (because I know I didn't come up with this), but I don't have notes on where I got it from (update: looks like I probably got it from here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vclanguage/thread/644c12ed-e3a7-4c5a-a73a-610fcc7913ca)...

```
#define __STR2__(x) #x
#define __STR1__(x) __STR2__(x)
#define __PPOUT__(x) "#define " #x " " __STR1__(x)

#if defined(_ATL_VER)
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_ATL_VER               ))
#endif

#if defined(_CHAR_UNSIGNED         )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_CHAR_UNSIGNED         ))
#endif

#if defined(__CLR_VER              )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__CLR_VER              ))
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus_cli        )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__cplusplus_cli        ))
#endif

#if defined(__COUNTER__            )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__COUNTER__            ))
#endif

#if defined(__cplusplus            )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__cplusplus            ))
#endif

#if defined(_CPPLIB_VER            )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_CPPLIB_VER            ))
#endif

#if defined(_CPPRTTI               )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_CPPRTTI               ))
#endif

#if defined(_CPPUNWIND             )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_CPPUNWIND             ))
#endif

#if defined(_DEBUG                 )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_DEBUG                 ))
#endif

#if defined(_DLL                   )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_DLL                   ))
#endif

#if defined(__FUNCDNAME__          )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__FUNCDNAME__          ))
#endif

#if defined(__FUNCSIG__            )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__FUNCSIG__            ))
#endif

#if defined(__FUNCTION__           )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__FUNCTION__           ))
#endif

#if defined(_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS     )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_INTEGRAL_MAX_BITS     ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_ALPHA               )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_ALPHA               ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_CEE                 )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_CEE                 ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_CEE_PURE            )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_CEE_PURE            ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_CEE_SAFE            )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_CEE_SAFE            ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_IX86                )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_IX86                ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_IA64                )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_IA64                ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_IX86_FP             )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_IX86_FP             ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_MPPC                )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_MPPC                ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_MRX000              )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_MRX000              ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_PPC                 )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_PPC                 ))
#endif

#if defined(_M_X64                 )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_M_X64                 ))
#endif

#if defined(_MANAGED               )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_MANAGED               ))
#endif

#if defined(_MFC_VER               )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_MFC_VER               ))
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_BUILD             )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_MSC_BUILD             ))
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_EXTENSIONS        )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_MSC_EXTENSIONS        ))
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_FULL_VER          )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_MSC_FULL_VER          ))
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_VER               )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_MSC_VER               ))
#endif

#if defined(__MSVC_RUNTIME_CHECKS  )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(__MSVC_RUNTIME_CHECKS  ))
#endif

#if defined(_MT                    )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_MT                    ))
#endif

#if defined(_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED)
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_NATIVE_WCHAR_T_DEFINED))
#endif

#if defined(_OPENMP                )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_OPENMP                ))
#endif

#if defined(_VC_NODEFAULTLIB       )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_VC_NODEFAULTLIB       ))
#endif

#if defined(_WCHAR_T_DEFINED       )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_WCHAR_T_DEFINED       ))
#endif

#if defined(_WIN32                 )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_WIN32                 ))
#endif

#if defined(_WIN64                 )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_WIN64                 ))
#endif

#if defined(_Wp64                  )
    #pragma message(__PPOUT__(_Wp64                  ))
#endif

void main() {}
```

Comment: This solution is good enough for me. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I don't see that option in the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx), but the list of predefined macros for Visual Studio [2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.90).aspx) and [2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay(VS.100).aspx) are available.